# Custom action not binding to custom content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, content-type, custom-action

I have created a custom content type and want to add a custom action to it but it is not working. I have tried editing the registrationid to the standard item content type id (0x01) and is works but not with my content type. Is it possible to add custom actions to custom content types???

Comment: Posting the Custom Action XML will help us to see whats happening. You can add custom actions to custom content types

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to my problem and thought I'd post it as I couldn't find anything online about it. When attaching custom actions to custom content types via Visual Studio, the id's that VS generates for the content types e.g "0x010100fd5b310cb7aa4b158fc2a8a4ab15dfae" isn't recognized by the custom action and therefore doesn't attach itself. I got around this problem by simplifying the id to "0x0101AB" and "0x0101ABAB" as the content types inherit from each other - keep in mind that the id's are simply concatenated in SharePoint to maintain it's hierarchy when doing so.

Hope this helps a couple of people as like I said, I couldn't and still can't find anything online regarding this issue...